# Draw on figure too large for screen?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have  an 800x800 double matrix that I need to draw little red dots on. I tried converting it to an image with mat2gray(array,[0,1]), but matlab scales it by 67% before it draws to my screen. That means I can't use plot(x,y,'r') to draw the little dots.

I have tried looking into overlaying images, making the figure invisible, etc, but I can't figure out how to do this. There must be a simple way. Any ideas?

Here is my current code:

```
%map is an 800x800 matrix of doubles
img = mat2gray(map,[0,1]);

hold on;
plot(point.x, point.y,'r.','MarkerSize',10);
hold off

img = imresize(img,0.66); %so that matlab doesn't yell at me
set(figHandle, 'visible','on');
imshow(img);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning Matlab gives when plotting an image bigger than the window size

> Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67%

Does not mean that it changes the size of your array or image. It means that it plot it at normal size and then zooms out that %. Your array is still 800x800. If you want to plot over it, the same x,y coordinates apply. For example

```
imshow(rand(1000))
% Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 67% 
%   In imuitools/private/initSize at 71
%   In imshow at 282 
hold on
plot(500,500,'r.','MarkerSize',100)
```

Will create this

[image]

As you can see, they red dot is in the middle of the image, as expected. You don't need to resize your image

Also in your case, if you plot first the points and then the image, the image will be displayed above the points, covering them, I suggest first plotting the image, and then the points.

Comment: This worked! But I'd like to prevent the warning message from displaying. Using imresize before imshow breaks this - how can I resize the image without distorting the points or without matlab having to do it automatically?

Comment: Matlab does not resize your image, it only displays it zoomed out. Your image matrix remains the same. You can safely ignore the warning, it will not affect the performance of any code around it. You can suppress warnings from showing, but I would heavily advise against it, since it could hide real problems later on. On the other hand, `imresize` does change your data, so you would also need to change the coordinates of your points to match